# ComboBox Selected Item couldn't calculated output Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a simple currency converter app in WPF C#. I need to convert the currency USD to Indian rupees or Srilankan rupees, but couldn't process the output.
Furthermore, I have done the design and code when I ran the application output not displayed and error also not displayed what was a problem I don't know. What I tried so far I attached the code below, please have a look.

**WPF design**

```xml
<Grid>

    <Label Content="Amount :"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxAmount"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="1"/>

    <Label Content="From :" 
           Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="0"/>

    <ComboBox  Name="CboFrom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="25"  Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.Column="1">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="USD"/>      
    </ComboBox>

    <Label Content="To :"
             Grid.Row="4"
             Grid.Column="0"/>

    <ComboBox  Name="CboTo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"   
               Width="100" Height="25"   Grid.Row="4" 
               Grid.Column="1">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Srilankan Rupees"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Indian Rupees"/>
    </ComboBox>

    <Label Content="Total :"
             Grid.Row="6"
             Grid.Column="0"/>

    <TextBox
        x:Name="TextBoxTotal"
        Grid.Row="6"
        Grid.Column="1"/> 

</Grid>

<StackPanel
         Grid.Row="8"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button
            Width="60"
            Height="30"
            Content="Convert"
        
            x:Name="ButtonConvert"
            Margin="10 0 10 0"
            Click="ButtonConvert_Click" Background="#FF04097E" Foreground="White"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**C# Code**

```cs
private void ButtonConvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double tot;
    double amount = double.Parse(TextBoxAmount.Text);

    if  (CboFrom.SelectedItem == "USD" && CboTo.SelectedItem == "Srilankan Rupees")
    {
        tot = amount * 179.50;
        TextBoxTotal.Text = tot.ToString();
    }
    else if (CboFrom.SelectedItem == "USD" && CboTo.SelectedItem == "Indian Rupees")
    {
        tot = amount * 70;
        TextBoxTotal.Text = tot.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a number of issues there.  Aren't you going to read at least the conversion rates from a service? You've mixed iso code and currency description.  You should probably have both in a Currency ViewModel.  Bind the combo boxes to a collection of these and selecteditem to just one.  More like https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged  Except of course currencies rather than people and you want to do the calculation in some code an icommand calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CboFrom.SelectedItem is not a string, it's a [ComboBoxItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).
What you want to compare is `((ComboBoxItem)CboFrom.SelectedItem).Content.ToString()`.

Which gives you:
`if (((ComboBoxItem)CboFrom.SelectedItem).Content.ToString() == "USD" && ((ComboBoxItem)CboTo.SelectedItem).Content.ToString() == "Srilankan Rupees")`

Whilst that will work, it is definitely hacky and bad design. I advise you look into EldHasp's suggestions to improve your design.

Comment: SelectedItem.Content.ToString().  there is no properties Content

Comment: AH you have to cast it to '((ComboBoxItem)SelectedItem).Content.ToString()

Comment: if  (CboFrom.SelectedValue == "USD" && CboTo.SelectedValue == "Srilankan Rupees") how to write this line

Comment: (CboFrom.(ComboBoxItem)SelectedItem). == "USD"  here this is not working

Comment: That's not how casting works, you can look into it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)
I've edited my answer to show you the correct way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You set a collection of UI elements in the ComboBox - ComboBoxItem. Therefore, you select a UI element. And it will not work to compare it with the value of the data.
According to the application logic, you need to set the data collection in the ComboBox source so that you can select this data.
In its simplest form, it would be something like this:

```cs
public static class SomeHelper
{
    public static ReadOnlyCollection CurrencyСodes {get;} = Array.AsReadOnly(new string[] {"USD"});
    public static ReadOnlyCollection CurrencyNames {get;} = Array.AsReadOnly(new string[] {"Srilankan Rupees", "Indian Rupees"});
}
```

```xml
    <ComboBox x:Name="CboFrom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="25"
              Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{x:Static local:SomeHelper.CurrencyСodes}"/>

    <ComboBox x:Name="CboTo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="25"
              Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{x:Static local:SomeHelper.CurrencyNames}"/>
```

```cs
private void ButtonConvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double tot;
    double amount = double.Parse(TextBoxAmount.Text);

    if (CboFrom.SelectedItem == SomeHelper.CurrencyСodes[0])
    {
        if (CboTo.SelectedItem == SomeHelper.CurrencyNames[0])
        {
            tot = amount * 179.50;
            TextBoxTotal.Text = tot.ToString();
        }
        else if (CboTo.SelectedItem == SomeHelper.CurrencyNames[1])
        {
            tot = amount * 70;
            TextBoxTotal.Text = tot.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.** But I would recommend that you implement a normal WPF-typical ViewModel. This will greatly simplify the code, make it easier to read and understand. Reduce the likelihood of various errors.

Comment: public static class SomeHelper   where i need to create this class

Comment: ReadOnlyCollection  get error when i create the SomeHelper

Comment: @abijega , Studio should prompt (in "Quick Solutions") to add `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;`.